# Using Contextual Filters and Panels

Tags: views

Hi Drupalites I need some help.

1.I was using relationship to output authors personal info associated with a piece of content which i did successfully. so i was trying something else but i didnt succeed.

I created a content type called State-Capital which has a list of of States and their respective capitals and I created another Content type called Misc Project which had different project details like Cost,Project Approve and State.Now i was trying to link the state field to output the capital associated with the respective state in Misc Project content type but i cudnt.The field name for States in both content type are same.Pls help.

1. I am trying to learn panels so wanted to know if there is any link or material for the same

Comment: Is state field (in Misc Project) a node-reference field to State-Capital nodes?

Comment: Well field names are same but i idnt use the node referne method initially.Now i hav tried using the node reference logic .I have added a field which is a node reference linking to the State-Capital node.Tell me how to proceed after that

Answer (score 0):

Ranjan is correct, you should add a node reference field to the **Project** content type so it can reference a **State-Capital**

In order to display any info about the state on the Project page you can use the [Views 3](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Reference](https://drupal.org/project/references) modules.

For this example let's say the node reference is labeled **"Project Location"**, and the State Capital is **Austin, Texas**.

Here are some steps you can follow:

**1) Create a View**

-- Create a new view block that displays State-Capital type nodes.

**2) Add a Relationship to the view**

-- Add a Relationship: **Content: Project Location**. This will allow you access to the fields of the Projects that reference **Austin, Texas**.

-- Give the relationship an identifier. Let's say `related_project`.

-- Save the relationship.

**3) Add a Contextual Filter to the view**

-- Add a Contextual Filter: **Content: Nid**.

-- Edit the contextual filter.

-- Set the Relationship in the contextual filter to related_project.

-- Look for WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL.

-- Set it to Provide default value -> Content ID from URL. This will get the nid of your Project.

-- Save the Contextual Filter.

-- Add in your fields. (Title at least)

**4) Test it**

To test in the preview, input the nid of your Project example as a contextual filter in *Preview with contextual filters:*

Save your view!

**5) Enable the block in your node pages**

After the view is complete, configure the new block to display in content type Projects.

I hope this helps.

Updated: 2014/06/18

Comment: updated the instructions.